# How can I get the average of the 3rd to 7th highest selection from three pandas columns?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

```
id      MaxS        MaxA    MaxD    
43290   9.511364    2.70    0.27    
43290   7.547727    2.56    0.34    
43290   7.465909    2.66    0.48    
43290   7.404545    3.90    0.60    
43290   7.772727    2.38    0.11    
43290   7.936364    2.62    0.97    
43290   7.650000    4.20    1.64    
43290   3.088636    1.79    0.06    
43290   4.377273    2.19    0.05    
43290   6.750000    4.65    1.90    
43290   5.461364    2.82    0.19    
43290   7.363636    4.13    1.48    
43290   11.270455   3.72    0.41    
43290   10.186364   3.88    1.17    
43290   3.109091    2.05    0.02    
43290   7.834091    3.38    0.01    
43290   3.252273    2.31    0.03    
43290   7.854545    3.00    0.70    
43290   9.756818    3.26    0.54    
43290   6.954545    2.93    0.24    
43291   4.070455    1.21    0.21    
43291   6.034091    3.42    0.42    
43291   8.018182    2.41    0.66    
43291   7.956818    3.55    0.62    
43291   8.161364    2.74    0.64    
43291   8.263636    4.11    0.13    
43291   2.618182    1.80    0.08    
43291   2.168182    2.12    0.04    
43291   6.095455    3.04    0.11    
43291   9.061364    2.91    0.33    
45880   5.236364    2.43    0.15    
45880   14.972727   4.86    0.23    
45880   9.593182    4.48    1.36    
45880   4.459091    3.67    0.14    
45880   17.325000   4.21    0.44    
45880   11.086364   3.30    1.00    
45880   5.277273    2.25    0.12    
45880   7.547727    2.92    0.34    
45880   11.270455   3.33    0.03    
45880   13.990909   3.21    0.50    
45880   9.122727    3.86    1.14    
45880   6.790909    4.24    1.30    
45880   8.100000    4.31    0.80    
45880   5.809091    3.22    0.94    
45881   6.565909    3.50    0.86    
45881   10.452273   4.64    0.85    
45881   7.281818    3.47    0.71    
45881   9.347727    3.67    0.02    
45881   14.318182   3.97    0.51    
45881   5.481818    3.99    0.21    
45881   7.425000    3.93    1.65    
45881   8.836364    3.50    0.26    
45881   5.277273    2.21    0.57    
45881   12.865909   4.38    0.94    
45881   7.200000    2.86    0.45    
45881   7.138636    4.39    1.18    
45881   8.815909    4.34    0.34    
45881   9.490909    4.53    0.28    
45881   17.652273   4.59    0.05    
45881   11.106818   2.64    0.31    
45881   9.511364    3.83    1.14    
45881   8.284091    3.90    0.20    
45881   9.306818    3.54    0.22    
45881   5.195455    2.66    0.14    
45881   3.477273    2.50    0.16    
45881   7.179545    3.70    0.08    
45881   8.447727    3.19    0.32    
45881   4.990909    2.32    0.86    
45881   16.465909   4.28    0.25
```

Hi all, as you can see I have the table above in a pandas dataframe. What I want to do is for every ID i would like the 3rd most to 7th most MaxS, MaxA and MaxD and I want to take an average of them. I know you can head or nlargest to get the top most numbers in these columns but I am not sure how to get the third most to seventh most for each ID. Also if you try nlargest on multiple columns pandas throws an error. So I'm not sure how to proceed with this problem.

Would really appreciate it if someone could help me find the average of the 3rd largest to 7th largest number in each of the three columns (MaxS, MaxA and MaxD) for each id.

Thank you!

Comment: Please repeat the intro tour, especially [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  "How do I code this program" is not a Stack Overflow issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting the data frame column to a *numpy array* can work:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def _get_average(column):
    """ perform sort, reverse and get 3rd to 7th values to average """
    return np.mean(np.sort(column.to_numpy())[::-1][3:8])

def average_csv():
    """ read data as csv and average the desired fields """
    my_df = pd.read_csv("my_csv.csv", delimiter="\s+")
    return _get_average(my_df["MaxS"]), _get_average(my_df["MaxA"]), _get_average(my_df["MaxD"])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("MaxS: {}, MaxA: {}, MaxD: {}".format(*average_csv()))
```